# Ubuntu update for 27 Feb 2018 failed

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2

Today's update of Ubuntu failed and left me with a system that boots to a GRUB prompt :

```
grub>
```

If I type `exit` I get another grub prompt.

If I type `ls` I get a message saying:

```
There was a failure reading from sector 0xfc on hd01.
```

I sense this is not good.  What should I do?

Comment: I had a similar problem and fixed it by typing 'normal` at the grub prompt.

Comment: I'd be worried its a warning sign for a hardware-failure (present or future), so would stop trying to use your hdd/boot-device to avoid stressing it.  I'd boot a live distro (eg. ubuntu install media) & use `smartctl` etc to view the status of your drives to check out its not hardware.  Only when satisfied your hardware is okay, would I try and 'fix'... (if hardware is dying, the more you do, the less you'll be able to get off easily..)

Comment: @guiverc because two people had the same problem after updates on Feb 27/2018 doesn't that point more to a software problem rather than hardware? You could be right given the sector message but I'd like to hear more about John Anderson's problem.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I believe my problem was caused by an upgrade to grub version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16. I'm not 100% sure how I ended up at the grub prompt ( I let the update run and wasn't watching it closely). It may or may not have rebooted to get there. At the grub prompt I tried several commands like 'halt', 'boot', 'reboot', all of which resulted in rebooting into the grub prompt. I finally tried the `normal` command, and that got me to the familiar grub boot menu, and it has been working fine ever since.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thank you for your recollections. I think it would be a worthwhile answer for others. Can you confirm if the timing of your update was close to OP's date?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, My update was on 23 Feb 2018

Comment: @JohnAnderson In `Settings`->`Software & Updates` -> `Updates` -> `Automatic Updates`, do you have it set for daily, every two days, weekly or every two weeks?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I have it set to check for updates daily, but only security updates are installed automatically.  In that particular case, I initiated the update after getting a notification.

Comment: Clark Allen can you tell us how often your system is setup to Automatically Check for Updates?

Comment: My system is set to check for updates daily, I think.  I see that an update is pending and am asked to select what I want to update from the list.  I always update everything on the suggested list.

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this use boot-repair :**

From a live usb, go to a terminal :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

**Choose Recommend Repair to fix your boot problem.**

Comment: The first prompt shows a gnome-terminal and the next ones show a grub prompt. The first looks like after successful boot and the other looks like when you can't boot.

Comment: Fixed. indeed. For me its obvious. But to explain is different. Either way i have changed my answer.

Comment: Yes I knew the different environments but the new people would be challenged.

Comment: Thank you.  The steps given above worked for me.  I am up and going again.  You rock.